# SystemEvent Prefab's GameObjects not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have Button **Prefab**. It's OnClick attached to EventSystem Prefab and select method called ( doIt ).

[image]

This method (doIt) print message and enable panel called ( Panel).

```
public void doIt()
{
    print("Doing !!!");
    helpCanvas.SetActive(true);
}
```

EventSystem **Prefab** has script which has method ( doIt ) and gameObject ( Button ) already attached to it

[image]

Panel **Prefab** is inactive

[image]

I draged these **Prefab** ( Button, EventSystem and Panel ) in some scenes (about 17 scenes) like this.

[image]

**The problem is:**
When i play the game there is nothing happen when i click button

[image]

, but the panel become enabled just after i stop the game

[image]

**Note:**
This happened only when the SystemEvent instance depend on prefab , but if i draged the panel manually from the scene 
[image]
and the SystemEvent instance to the OnClick this not happened
[image]

Why this happened ? and how to solve that ?
It doesn't suit me or to any one to reattach the Button OnClick EventSystem Manually for all buttons which has the same function. Or to attach Panel instance to each EventSystem Instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefabs cannot have references to objects within a scene. This is because every time Unity instantiates the prefab, how is it supposed to know if the object referenced is still there. The workaround is to add a script component on your button prefab, and then create a function inside that which preforms your desired actions. Your button prefab can have a reference **only** to things which are local to it (not scene dependent, will be there every time the prefab is instantiated). After you instantiate the object, your master script can do buttonInstantiatedPrefabName.GetComponent().evsys = evsys; This way, all your editor references will be stored in a master script, which will assign it to other gameObjects which are instantiated from prefabs.

Comment: Nice ,
Now i defined the Panel on start:
    void Start () {
        GameObject panel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Panel");
        panel.SetActive(false);
    }
    void doIt(){
        print("Test"):
        panel.SetActive(true);
    }
but the button still can't read it

Comment: You should test if the panel is being found correctly. Also, instead of using GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag, store references in a master script and assign them to the instantiated objects.

Comment: "store references in a master script"
using code ? or drag and drop ?
if u mean using code can u explain how to catch prefab references ?